# Is there a code to inject a javascript to website to change the width of a pane?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the width of a pane by injecting a javascript code in google chrome. I want that code to be saved as a bookmark and whenever I click on that bookmark the changes will take effect on the website. I can manually change the width by going to inspect, navigation pane and change the width and css but it is a hassle doing that all the time when I am on the website, so I want to automate it.

What I basically want to achieve is to replace the following code

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="region" aria-label="Navigation pane" class="_25oA4qBLP_b6P080cw5s2H css-43" data-min-width="198" data-max-width="320">
```

to

```
<div tabindex="-1" role="region" aria-label="Navigation pane" class="_25oA4qBLP_b6P080cw5s2H css-50" data-min-width="198" style="width: 550px;">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `<div>` with `querySelector` or whichever method you prefer, and then assign to its `style` property:

```
const div = document.querySelector('div[role="region"]');
div.style.width = '550px';
```

In bookmarklet code:

```
javascript: (document.querySelector('div[role="region"]').style.width = '550px', undefined)
```

Note that if you want this to happen every time you visit the site, rather than clicking a bookmarklet every time, you might consider using a userscript instead, which will run the Javascript you want automatically, when the page loads. (A popular userscript manager is [Tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net).)

Since this looks like pure CSS, You could also use [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en) to achieve this - just type in whatever CSS you want:

```
div[role="region"] {
  width: 550px;
}
```

If you want to change the class name as well, then use `classList.remove` and `classList.add`:

```
div.classList.remove('css-43');
div.classList.add('css-50');
```

(that part can't be done in CSS alone)

Comment: Thank you, do I have to change something in that code? Like putting javascript: at the front? I saved it as a bookmark and clicked on it but nothing happened :-(

Comment: The bookmarklet code already has `javascript:` at the front - it should work as-is. Still, I highly recommend using a userscript instead, they're far more readable, flexible, and generally manageable than bookmarklets

Comment: OMG, it worked. It moved a bit. can you also show me the code how to insert the css. I want it at 50. How do i do that?

Comment: What do you mean? The `const div = document.querySelector('div[role="region"]');
div.style.width = '550px';` will change the CSS. If you want to use Stylus, use the `div[role="region"] {
  width: 550px;
}` code. You could also insert the CSS using a userscript. If you want a width of 50, change the number to 50 instead of 500

Comment: I checked it in inspect, your code has changed the width from 320 to 550, which is great. There is one part of the original code <div tabindex="-1" role="region" aria-label="Navigation pane" class="_25oA4qBLP_b6P080cw5s2H css-43" data-min-width="198" data-max-width="320">         I would also like to change the css-43 to css-50. Is that possible? All from the bookmark.

Comment: Use `classList.remove`

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit thick, could you show me the full bookmarklet code? Where do I place the classList.remove in javascript: (document.querySelector('div[role="region"]').style.width = '550px', undefined)

Comment: You should really consider using the userscript method - it makes the code so much easier to work with. If you *have* to use the bookmarklet method, use an IIFE so you can define a variable: `(() => { const div = document.querySelector('div[role="region"]');
div.style.width = '550px'; div.classList.remove('css-43');
div.classList.add('css-50'); })()` But strongly consider using a userscript instead

Comment: IT WORKED!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! This is amazing, thanks a lot.